# Change column number for a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the column number for a specific product category named 'inspiration' and its subcategories but whatever I try in the functions.php file, nothing happen.

I'm using Salient theme and it's Woocommerce columns are defined as :

- Archive Page Columns (Desktop) -> 5
- Archive Page Columns (Small Desktop) -> 4
- Archive Page Columns (Tablet) -> 3
- Archive Page Columns (Phone) -> 3

Maybe I'm doing wrong but here's my current code :

```
// Change number of columns for specific category and its subcategories
function change_category_columns($columns) {
    if (is_product_category('inspiration')) {
        return 3; // Set the number of columns for the 'inspiration' category
    }
    return $columns; // Retain the default number of columns for other categories
}
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'change_category_columns', 999);
```

Thanks for your help